# Strange error in swift when using count()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I get a strange error when using `count()`
So I have these methods

```
func count(ch:String)->Int {

    let chars = Set(ch)
    var fu = removeUnwantaedCharacters(strand, set: chars)
    let bli:String = fu
    return 0
}

func removeUnwantaedCharacters(text: String, set characterSet: Set<Character>) -> String {

    return String(filter(text) { characterSet.contains($0) })
}
```

This works fine. 
Let's say I want the length of fu and add

```
count(fu)
```

(forget about the bli....)

I get an error:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 and the error is at the return statement of the removeUnwantedCharacters function.

Does that make any sense??

Thanks for help!

Comment: Where have you defined fu? Edit: So you're returning `count(fu)` from the function I suppose

Comment: Can it be that by calling `count(fu)` you're calling the same function again resulting in a loop? If you want to use Swifts count function you have to use `Swift.count(fu)`

Comment: OMG I totally forgot I named my function count -.- -.-
I'm ashamed of my stupidity -,- Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift have already one `count` function like this:

```
func count<T : _CollectionType>(x: T) -> T.Index.Distance
```

so change your `count` function name because it is confusing compiler.